# Why using "opacity" or an "absolute position" ruin my "transform: rotateY(180deg)" on chrome ? any idea how to fix it?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-animations

I have a card made with html and css, the card can rotate (180° on Y) and in it's back I want to have an image with an opacity of 0.3 and some texts with set position (see exemple below).

When I use css opacity or an absolute position for something, the `transform: rotateY(180deg);` is buggy **on Chrome**, there is a +/-1 second delay before the back of the card appear.
Warning : **the bug occur only once, the first time the `rotateY` is used; to do it again, you need to reload the page (F5).**

gif of my card:

[image: gif1]

Everything works fine on firefox; I tested with 2 computers on Chrome and both have the bug/delay.

I have no clue what to try, I tried to not use the css `opacity` by using color code as rgba but I didn't find the same result

exemple of absolute position for text :

```
.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}
```

exemple of opacity :

```
.changeOpacity {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

I made a codepen : https://codepen.io/Demky/pen/pozWZKM

here is a gif of the problem on codepen :

[image: gif codepen]

if you comment or remove the html code of the formated back of the card, there is no more bug, same if you remove the css classes : `.bottom-right` and `.changeOpacity`

I also tried on the w3chools website and it do the same bug with their template/exemple:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_flip_card

[image: w3school]

if you add `opacity:0.3;` in the css classe `.flip-card-back` it does the same, so I don't think the problem is from me.

Is it working as intended ? 
Any idea what to do ? 
isn't it possible to change the opacity/position of something in the back of a card ?

Let me know if my question isn't clear.

Comment: Do u want the entire text align vertically middle?

Comment: not for the moment, I let it at default position for the snippet to be more clear; here is a screenshot of the "final result" i had. Each text have his own position : https://i.imgur.com/XgDPalE.png

Comment: Remove `backface-visibility: hidden` maybe? Or at least from `.flip-card-back`. If I do that, the effect seems to disappear.

Comment: I tried it; it "fix" the problem on Chrome but it create a new one on Firefox : when you remove `backface-visibility: hidden` On firefox the back of the card is now in front of the face ; see : https://i.imgur.com/ADgywF8.png ;

Comment: This question has been answered over on [the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/21251-probleme-css-rotatey-and-opacityposition-can-i-use-gsap-or-would-it-be-overkill/?tab=comments#comment-99822)